# Problems opening port 80 in w7

Tags: windows-7, server, port

I am having problems setting up my http server. I have routed my domain to my public ip.
I can view my website at [my public ip].org

Here are my router settings:
[image]

Here is my firewall settings for the port
[image]

I can view the website at local internet but foreign IP's cannot access it. 
This link says that port 80 is closed
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Ping results:
[image]

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The only external IP i was forwarding was my own public ip.
From my router settings, I changed the External IP address to 0.0.0.0.